# JavaScript carousel slider not working past the second slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I am trying to create a JS carousel, and it is somewhat working, but not quite. After I clicked on the 'right' button, it slides to the second slide, but when I click it again, it gives the error 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add). This goes for the adding of the 'active' class to the nextSlide I presume, but I can't seem to grasp what I am doing wrong. Also gives the error 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextElementSibling')' when I tried to click to the third slide.

```
// CAROUSEL
const carousel = document.querySelector(".cards-wrapper");
const slides = [...carousel.children];
const nextButton = document.querySelector(".button-right");
const previousButton = document.querySelector(".button-left");

let slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect();

function positionSlides(slides) {
  for (let index = 0; index < slides.length; index++) {
    slides[index].style.left = slideWidth * index + "px";
  }
}

positionSlides(slides);

nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const currentSlide = carousel.querySelector(".active");
  const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling.getBoundingClientRect();

  const position = nextSlide.width;
  console.log(position);
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${position}px)`;

  currentSlide.classList.remove("active");
  nextSlide.classList.add("active");
});
```

```
<div class="carousel">
          <div class="cards-wrapper">
            <div class="card active">
              <picture>
                <img src="https://s3.envato.com/files/158241052/1.jpg" alt="" />
              </picture>
              <h3>Slide 1</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id
                perspiciatis cumque consectetur vero eaque inventore fuga, nobis
                reiciendis repudiandae, eius quo odio rem, esse saepe fugiat
                quos deserunt dignissimos dolorem.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <picture>
                <img src="https://s3.envato.com/files/158241052/1.jpg" alt="" />
              </picture>
              <h3>Slide 2</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id
                perspiciatis cumque consectetur vero eaque inventore fuga, nobis
                reiciendis repudiandae, eius quo odio rem, esse saepe fugiat
                quos deserunt dignissimos dolorem.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <picture>
                <img src="https://s3.envato.com/files/158241052/1.jpg" alt="" />
              </picture>
              <h3>Slide 3</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id
                perspiciatis cumque consectetur vero eaque inventore fuga, nobis
                reiciendis repudiandae, eius quo odio rem, esse saepe fugiat
                quos deserunt dignissimos dolorem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="button-left">left</button>
          <button class="button-right">right</button>
          <div class="carousel-nav">
            <button class="active">1</button>
            <button>2</button>
            <button>3</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried logging out what `nextSlide` is at that point?

Comment: Yes, but it does not get that far: It gives the error 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextElementSibling')' before it has a chance to log

Comment: That error is due to `nextElementSibling` returning null for the last element in a parent element, you'll need to check for `null` and I guess loop your carousel (depending on the desired effect)

Comment: But shouldn't that happen after I click on the 'right' button at the third slide? Because that's where there is no `nextElementSibling`

Comment: Oh, yeah you're assigning the `getBoundingClientRect()` to `nextSlide`, and then trying to access the `classList` on that rather than the element.

Comment: Ah okay, how can I fix this? Because when I remove that, the sliding does not work anymore.

Comment: Well, since you need both the bounding rect and the element, I would set `const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;` and then use `const position = nextSlide.getBoundingClientRect().width;` to find the position.

Comment: I see. done. Now it correctly logs the 2 following slides, but it does not slide from the second to the third slide.. When I click on the button, it logs the `nextSlide`, but nothing happens and when I click it again, the error of `null` pops up, which is to be expected.

Comment: I imagine that's because you are translating the carousel by the width of a single slide each time (and the width of each slide is probably the same) you'll need to multiply the width by the slide index. e.g. `\`translateX(-${position * index}px)\`` (you will need to work out the index)

Comment: That does not make sense to me, because yes the slide size remains the same. And the carousel needs to transform twice. But only transforms once.

Comment: Think about it like this: To start with the carousel is at `0`, on the first click you translate it to `-width`, on the second click you set the translation to `-width` again, which is the same position as before (translations apply to the elements original position, they don't stack together)

Comment: Ah I see. I do not know how to define the `index`. I tried `slides.length`, but to no avail.